# How to form the Merge query when there are multiple key columns?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

On snowflake database, I am trying to run a merge on a table: `PK_TABLE_TEST`. This table DDL is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "LOAD".pk_table_test (
     RESORT STRING NOT NULL, 
     STAYDATE DATE NOT NULL, 
     RATE_CODE STRING NOT NULL, 
     RNS NUMBER (38, 0), 
     GST NUMBER (38, 0), 
     REVENUE FLOAT, 
     REPORT_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
     SYS_INS_DATE timestamp,
     PRIMARY KEY (RESORT),
     UNIQUE(RESORT, STAYDATE, RATE_CODE, REPORT_DATE)
);
```

I have the same table on my staging database with the name: `pk_table_test_stg`.
In my store procedure, I formed a merge query by getting all the keys from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Below is the merge query:

```
MERGE INTO LOAD.PK_TABLE_TEST target USING LOAD.PK_TABLE_TEST_STG stg ON target.RESORT = stg.RESORT and target.STAYDATE = stg.STAYDATE and target.RATE_CODE = stg.RATE_CODE and target.REPORT_DATE = stg.REPORT_DATE WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.RESORT = stg.RESORT,target.STAYDATE = stg.STAYDATE,target.RATE_CODE = stg.RATE_CODE,target.RNS = stg.RNS,target.GST = stg.GST,target.REVENUE = stg.REVENUE,target.REPORT_DATE = stg.REPORT_DATE,target.SYS_INS_DATE = '2020-10-10 4:35:24'; WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (RESORT,STAYDATE,RATE_CODE,RNS,GST,REVENUE,REPORT_DATE,SYS_INS_DATE) VALUES (stg.RESORT,stg.STAYDATE,stg.RATE_CODE,stg.RNS,stg.GST,stg.REVENUE,stg.REPORT_DATE,stg.SYS_INS_DATE);
```

But when I run the query, it says `unexpected WHEN`.

```
SQL Error [1003] [42000]: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 2 at position 272 unexpected 'WHEN'.
```

Is there any syntax error with the query I formed ? Is it the right syntax when there are multiple columns in the `ON` condition ?
Could anyone let me know how can I fix the issue ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semicolon in your query:

target.SYS_INS_DATE = '2020-10-10 4:35:24'; WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT

Try to delete this one :-)

More info about the syntax (which looks correct) can be found  here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

Comment: Thanks Marcel. You are correct, semicolon was the issue. I removed it after the first `WHEN` and the query completed as expected.